# How to set c# struct attribute (StructLayoutAttribute) globally?

Tags: pinvoke

I'm working on a c# p/invoke project and defining a lot of structures. For each structure, I'm using:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```

But Now I'd like to set the attribute(**Pack = 1**) only once so that all my structures share the same setting, How can I do that?

Thanks,
Fei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. There is no global switch. You have to set `Pack` explicitly on every struct.

You can at least make you code more concise by adding a `using` statement, and by writing `StructLayout` rather than `StructLayoutAttribute`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

....
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
```